# MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS vs MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I wrote a hello world device driver recipe and when i am trying to install it in the root file system, using the following variable in qemux86-64.conf

```
MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS = += " kernel-module-hello"
```

The above line is not inserted in the module in root file system but the below line does

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += " kernel-module-hello"
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these both variables. Which one should be used when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS :** list of machine-specific packages to install in the image being built that are **not essential** for the machine to boot. Usually used to add features. And, as stated by the manual:

  > This variable affects all images based on packagegroup-base, which
  >   does not include the core-image-minimal or core-image-full-cmdline
  >   images.
- **MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS :** list of machine-specific packages to install in the image being built that are **essential** for the machine to boot. And, as stated by the manual:

  > The impact of this variable affects images based on
  >   packagegroup-core-boot, including the core-image-minimal image.

It's highly likely that your image is not based on packagegroup-base, but packagegroup-core-boot. Besides, I would like to point out that kernel modules are usually (and this seems to be your case) included in either `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS` or `MACHINE_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS` instead of `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS` or `MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS`.

For further information refer to https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS

PD: Whitespace-separator is not needed when appending a variable with the **+=** operator. Also, you have a typo here:

> MACHINE_EXTRA_RDEPENDS **= +=** " kernel-module-hello"

Comment: Correct, core-image-minimal is only having packagegroup-core-boot.